# Highcharts export issue

Tags: highcharts

i am using highcharts and having an issue while download. Initially after the chart is displayed we are modifying it in the load function of events object. Now when i export the chart it is taking the default parameters of the chart( i.e height and width) and not the updated ones. how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did u do chart.redraw after resizing it? Can u post the code or jsFiddle link to replicate the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to use [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions). In other cases please replicate your issue as live demo